VS Code incoming/outgoing changes disapeared from source control tab
Recently (like around 2 weeks ago), something changed in VS Code and now I don't see incoming/outgoing changes. I tried searching for the solution, but it seems there were new updates and most of the information is already outdated.

I know that couple of months ago there was an update that changed the previous incoming/outgoing view to a graph: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_92#_incomingoutgoing-changes-graph
But I did not like it and immediately disabled it with scm.experimental.showHistoryGraph: false option. Now I see that I used experimental flag instead of a normal one, but it was working fine for some time. And then it broke. Now I don't see neither graph nor the previous incoming/outgoing thingy.
It seems that there was new update that moved the graph around: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_93#_source-control
But I don't have it anywhere and I don't know how to enable it. Also I still would like to have the old view. I'm not sure if it has something to do with the fact, that I moved the source control tab inside a different tab?
I tried searching on the internet and I found bunch of options that supposedly should control visibility of these features. But in my preferences I don't see any one of them:

scm.showHistoryGraph
scm.showIncomingChanges
scm.showOutgoingChanges
scm.showChangesSummary

I tried deleting all of my VS Code preferences but it didn't help.
What should I do now?

Having this issue as well. This was hands down one of the best additions to vscode (before they added the graph part). To quickly be able to see what you are pulling in in a convinient way was great.
The only solution I have seen so far is to downgrade to 1.91. But this is not a long term solution.
